# Salesforce Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps, keyboard

Can we use any keyboard shortcuts in Salesforce Apps? Not Console apps.
I only found from [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessibility_keyboard_shortcuts_lex.htm&type=5)

`e` -> edit

`/` -> navigate to search

`esc` -> close create/edit record

The others do not seem to work.

Also, if they exist, are they configurable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Lightning Experience, keyboard shortcuts work in Lightning apps but not in Classic apps. If you have access to your org's Setup screens, you can also check if an App is Lightning or Classic by going to Setup > Apps > App Manager, and viewing the “App Type” column in the apps grid.

Another easy way to check if keyboard shortcuts are supported in your current app is to press `Ctrl + /` (Windows) or `Cmd + /` (OS X) to see if the shortcuts panel shows up.

Keyboard shortcuts in Lightning apps are contextual, so some of them only work when you have their associated features available in your current Salesforce browser window. For example:

- **m** works when you have the Macro utility in your app’s utility bar (at bottom of window)
- **n** works when you have the Notes utility in your app’s utility bar
- **g, then p** works on any page that has a publisher component on it
- **g, then d** (go to Docked Composer Window) works if you’ve opened any composer windows in your current session, such as if you’ve selected a Global Action that launched a record creation window in the bottom corner of your screen

Note that the **c** key for focusing notifications refers to [individual, dismissible notifications](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/#site-main-content), not the notifications dropdown menu represented by the bell icon.

At present, there isn’t a way to customize keyboard shortcuts in Salesforce Lightning.